# Applying a key value dictionary pair to multiple column in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to apply changes into current dataframe in 2 columns with a dictionary key to one column and value to another column for each value coming from dict. I am not able to find any way to do that for eg.

```
dict is - test = {'a':32, 'b':21, 'c':92}
```

current dataframe looks forms like

```
date         env   result         cost

2021-03-01   dev      gcp.dev.a         30
2021-03-01   prd      gcp.prd.d         35
2021-03-01   dev      gcp.dev.j         98
2021-03-01   sandbox  gcp.sandbox.b     94
```

after adding changes from the dictionary on result and cost column dataframe should look like below -

```
date         env        result          cost

2021-03-01   dev      gcp.dev.a           30
2021-03-01   prd      gcp.prd.d           35
2021-03-01   dev      gcp.dev.j           98
2021-03-01   sandbox  gcp.sandbox.b       94
2021-03-01   dev      gcp.dev.a           32 
2021-03-01   prd      gcp.prd.b           21  
2021-03-01   prd     gcp.prd.c          92
```

here gcp is a fixed value, that is being added  and dev and prd is being coming from env column.

above you notice last 3 rows are being added by taking test dictionary key values each being added in result and cost. i.e relevant row should be added in both the columns for each key value pair

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this by using `pd.DateFrame.from_dict()` method,`append()` method and `ffill()` method:

```
test = {'a':32, 'b':21, 'c':92}

newdf=pd.DataFrame(test.values(),index=test.keys(),columns=['cost']).reset_index()
    #OR(use any one of them to create dataframe named newdf)
newdf=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test,orient='index',columns=['cost']).reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'result'})
```

Finally:

```
newdf=df.append(newdf,ignore_index=True).ffill()
```

Now If you print `newdf` you will get your desired output:

```
    date         result     cost
0   2021-03-01      a       30
1   2021-03-01      d       35
2   2021-03-01      j       98
3   2021-03-01      b       94
4   2021-03-01      a       32
5   2021-03-01      b       21
6   2021-03-01      c       92
```

Comment: I had a chained one but same approach really `df.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test, orient='index', columns=['cost']).rename_axis(['result'], axis=0).reset_index()).ffill()`

Comment: Sure Sir...I removed....I found it more efficient so I added it...Sorry for that  **:)**

Comment: is it feasible to make some changes in this command to accomedate the result ````acc['result'] = acc.apply(lambda x: [f'{squ}' for squ, cost in test.items()], axis=1) ```` using lambda ?

Comment: if you want individual value of 'result' column is of type `str` then you can do `acc['result']=str([f'{squ}' for squ, cost in test.items()])` **and** if  you want individual value of 'result' column is of type `list` then use `acc['result']=acc['result'].apply(lambda x: [f'{squ}' for squ, cost in test.items()])`

Comment: I want the same output where cost and result column are adding from test dict, but if u see my question now, I need to add other variables which are being added in result column with dict key. so that's the issue.

Comment: For that create a dict `d={'dev':'gcp.dev.a','prd':'gcp.prd.b','test':'gcp.test.c','sandbox':'gcp.sandbox.b'}` then `newdf=pd.DataFrame(test.values(),index=test.keys(),columns=['cost']).reset_index()` now assign new columns to **newdf** by `newdf['env']=['dev','prd','prd']`
`newdf['result']=newdf['env'].apply(lambda x:d[x])`  Now finally `df.append(newdf,ignore_index=True).ffill().drop(columns=['index'])`

Answer (score 1):

Create new DataFrame by cosntructor and add it to original by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), last forward filling `date` values:

```
test  = {'a':32, 'b':21, 'c':92}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(test.items()), columns=['result','cost'])

df = pd.concat([df, df1], ignore_index=True)
df['date'] = df['date'].ffill()
print (df)
         date result  cost
0  2021-03-01      a    30
1  2021-03-01      d    35
2  2021-03-01      j    98
3  2021-03-01      b    94
4  2021-03-01      a    32
5  2021-03-01      b    21
6  2021-03-01      c    92
```

Loops solution is possible, but slow, so not recommended:

```
for k, v in test.items():
    df.loc[len(df), ['result','cost']] = (k, v)

df['date'] = df['date'].ffill()
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `result` and `cost` as index:

```
temp = df.set_index(['result', 'cost'])
```

Build `MultiIndex` from dictionary:

```
test_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(test.items(), names = ['result', 'cost'])
```

Reindex `temp` with the union of `temp`'s index and `test_index`:

```
(temp
 .reindex(temp.index.union(test_index, sort = False))
 .ffill() 
 .reset_index()
 .reindex(columns = df.columns)
 )
 
         date result  cost
0  2021-03-01      a    30
1  2021-03-01      d    35
2  2021-03-01      j    98
3  2021-03-01      b    94
4  2021-03-01      a    32
5  2021-03-01      b    21
6  2021-03-01      c    92
```